# Why does this ETF appear to have price drops that are (virtually) infinite over the last 5 years?

Tags: etf, vanguard

According to Yahoo Finance, the `Vanguard` ETF `VERX.AS` has several (almost) infinite drops if you look at it over the last 5 years (I don't provide the link because it is extremely long, but below there is a capture):

[image: VERX.AS over 5 years]

(You can go to yahoo finance, search `VERX.AS`, got to chart and then 5 years.)

Can someone explain to me why does this happen with this ETF?

Comment: The drops are not infinite.  They can't be larger than the value of the fund before the drop, otherwise people who owned shares of the fund would be owing money to someone - and if it was an infinite drop, they could pay all the money in the universe, and still owe an infinite amount :-)  I strongly suspect that what's going here is that the drops are simply days with missing data, which is treated as zero by the graphing software.  Use a program that understands missing values.

Comment: It is obvious that whoever makes the chart tools failed to compensate day with missing data.

Comment: @jamesqf Yes, they are not infinite. It was only a manner of speaking. (BTW I have written 'virtually' infinite)

Comment: @jamesqf - Suspecting that missing days of data are being treated as zero is incorrect.  The data exists each day except that it's a mishmosh of two different data sets, for whatever the reason.  I've added a sample of it to my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yahoo is notorious for providing bad data.  If you go into the Historical Data that they provide you'll see that on one day the closing price is around  28p and the next day it is arould 2,400p

Try this on for size: [CHART](https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/fund/verx?countrycode=UK)

Here's a sample of the bad data:

> Jul 03, 2017       29.08      29.09      29.08      29.09    27.35      990
>
> Jun 30, 2017  2,547.00 2,564.89 2,535.00 2,537.00 2,385.47   30,569
>
> Jun 29, 2017  2,603.00 2,597.45 2,546.00 2,549.00 2,396.75   56,444
>
> Jun 28, 2017  2,605.00 2,611.00 2,583.00 2,587.00 2,432.48   71,458
>
> Jun 27, 2017     29.59    29.59    29.59    29.59    27.82      637
>
> Jun 26, 2017  2,600.00 2,621.00 2,602.28 2,612.00 2,455.99        7